# Changing a melted table back into a table

Tags: r, melt

Titanic is a data set in **R** whose class is "table".
`dim(Titanic)` tells it is 4-dimensional.
Now, if I do

```
x <- Titanic
y <- melt(x)
```

y looks like a 2-dimensional data frame.
My question is, how can I change y back to x? The closest I could get was by

```
z <- table(y)
```

But then z is 5-dimensional.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: How about sharing an example of your data set?

Comment: Which `melt` are you using (from which package)? `reshape2`?

Comment: @R Yoda: Yes, I am using reshape2 package.

Comment: @J. Win: Titanic is a built-in data, I think. I didn't make it. It was in R.

Comment: `xtabs(value ~ ., y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much `melt`ed about the result of `reshape2::melt(Titaninc)`. Compare with the result of `as.data.frame(Titanic)`. The only difference is the name of 'numbers' column (`value` vs `Freq`).

By doing `class(Titanic)` and `?table` you find out that the `Titanic` is type of data that comes out of the `table()` function. In the documentation you can also notice that there is `xtabs`, formula based interface to tabulation. In `xtabs` docs, `formula` argument says

> ... On the left hand side, one may optionally give a vector or a matrix of counts; in the latter case, the columns are interpreted as corresponding to the levels of a variable. This is useful if the data have already been tabulated, ...

Which leaves you with a simple

```
dt <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
xtabs( Freq ~ Class + Sex + Age + Survived, data = dt )
```

to reconstruct the `table` classed data, should you ever need it for some other package as input.

Tto add my two cents, working with a crosstab in a form of a simple two dimensional `data.frame` or better a `tibble` from `tidyverse` is much more advisable!

Comment: Using identical() function, it does not seem to be exactly identical to the original Titanic, but it is identical enough for my purpose, and this is the kind of simple solution I wanted. Thanks a lot liborm. I will check out tidyverse too. It seems cool.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an existing function to do this.  But, after using `dput` to look at the output of `reshape2::melt(Titanic)` we can use parts of that and feed the correct pieces into `reshape2::acast` to "unmelt" the table:

```
library(reshape2)

unmelt_table <- function(melted_table, value.name = "value") {

  premelt_dimnames <- names(melted_table)[names(melted_table) != value.name]
  premelt_dimlabels <- sapply(premelt_dimnames, function(n)
    levels(getElement(melted_table, n))
  )
  formula_colnames <- rev(premelt_dimnames)
  recast_formula <- as.formula(paste0(". ~ ", paste(formula_colnames, collapse = " + ")))
  premelt_vec <- as.vector(acast(melted_table, recast_formula))
  structure(premelt_vec, 
            .Dim = as.vector(sapply(premelt_dimlabels, length)),
            .Dimnames = premelt_dimlabels,
            class = "table")
}
```

To verify that it worked, just run this:

```
> identical(Titanic, unmelt_table(melt(Titanic)))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi J. Win, I tried your function but get an error
object 'cast_colnames' not found
But thank you anyway!

Comment: I had slipped in a typo, fixed it now... if you find the answers useful please consider upvote or checking the correct answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I voted for it. Yes, it works now! Thanks a lot!!